# Creating a json using php for ajax live searching using a .txt as its original data source

Tags: php, json

I have a very basic program that I have very botchfully outputted as a json, probably wouldn't even work as a ajax search in its current form.

But I am not sure how would be the most efficient way for me to search the array, I have been looking at array_filter and for each.

I have put $_GET for now but I do eventually intend to use post, it just makes it easier for me to test.

My current code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$q = $_GET['q'];

$locks = array();
$handle = fopen("lock.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    //echo "Last modified: ".date("F d Y H:i:s.",filemtime("lock.txt")). "<br>";
    $i=1;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $line=str_replace("\n","",$line);
        $data = explode("|", $line);
        $locks[$i] = array(
            port => $data[0],
            user=> $data[1],
            record => $data[2]
        );
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "Unable to open file, check that it exists";
}
echo json_encode($locks);
?>
```

Example data from lock.txt:

```
48|Romina Xxxxx|PPP*SALE*B686987
122|Charlotte Yyyyy|PPP*SALE*O944047
```

Current Example output (spaced out manually):

```
{"1":{
      "port":"48",
      "user":"Romina Xxxxx",
      "record":"PPP*SALE*B686987"},
  "2":{
       "port":"122",
       "user":"Charlotte Yyyyy",
       "record":"PPP*SALE*O944047"}
}
```

What I would need to do is search using the record but so that it has a wildcard search from whatever as I can't always be sure of the key, so I can't have only searching PPP before it shows what I want, nor can I always do O9xxxx as it may be that the content in the middle is the thing that needs to be searched, but it will always only be the record that is searched, the port and user just needs to be outputted when I do the ajax search.

Many thanks for your previous time.

Comment: seems kind of wasteful to continually load/replace/explode the file.w hy not store your data as a `serialize()` array, or even as json directly? `echo json_encode(unserialize(file_get_contents('lock.txt')))` or `echo file_get_contents('lock.json')` would be somewhat more efficient.

Comment: Sorry Marc i'm a bit unsure what you mean. if I don't somewhat clean up this txt file I have /n and I need to split it out based on the pipe delimiter, I know its very messy at the minute, which is why I am trying to see what can be done, the array has to be built up some way if I am not using mysql.

Comment: So are you saying you want to return a list of objects where the "record" property contains the value of "q"? So if "q" equals "944" then the returned object only contains the port 122 object? But if "q" equals "SALE" then both objects are returned?

Comment: Updated: I would like to return the whole of an id of contents if I did a search based on a record e.g. if q had B6 or SALE or PPP as the record needs to be a wildcard search from both ends, it would return port: 48, user: Romina XXXx, Record: PPP*SALE*B6....

Comment: @MarcB makes a good suggestion if you have control over the Text file itself. When you read the content of the text file, you just read in the serialized data. This can be parsed much faster into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your search isn't greedy, in other words, your output can be lenient a fast way to search for your input is using php's `strpos()`. Much faster than say `preg_match()`.

This method will allow you to search for segments inside your `record` without the need for wildcards and the likes.

### Examples

```
strpos('PPP*SALE*B686987', 'SALE'); // output: 4 i.e. SALE exists in the segment
strpos('PPP*SALE*B686987', 'PPP'); // output: 0
strpos('PPP*SALE*B686987', 'B68'); // output: 9
strpos('PPP*SALE*B686987', '987'); // output: 13
strpos('PPP*SALE*B686987', 'j'); // output: false
```

### When/How to do the search

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$q = $_GET['q'];

// It is primordial to sanitize the
// your import (further details in the
// Recommendation section

$locks = array();
$handle = fopen("lock.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    //echo "Last modified: ".date("F d Y H:i:s.",filemtime("lock.txt")). "<br>";
    $i=1;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // Parse the line and add it to the
        // array as long as the output
        // of strpos is not false
        if (strpos($line, $q))
        {
            $line=str_replace("\n","",$line);
            $data = explode("|", $line);
            $locks[$i] = array(
                port => $data[0],
                user=> $data[1],
                record => $data[2]
            );
        }
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "Unable to open file, check that it exists";
}
echo json_encode($locks);
?>
```

### Recommendations

I cannot stress enough the **importance** of **sanitizing** your input through `$_GET` or `$_POST`. It's a major security concern. You can some more reading about `filter_input()` in [PHP online manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

Comment: Niicce! I know it is messy, I am just trying to make my life easier at work with these locked records. I really appreciate this.

Comment: If you don't want to search the entire line, such as `48|Romina Xxxxx|PPP*SALE*B686987`, then only wrap your `$locks[$i]` assignment with the conditional, and change `$line` to `$data[2]`.